# vbscript save wmi to xml

Tags: xml, vbscript, wmi

Please need help. 
My script is

```
    Set objService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\.\Root\CIMV2") 
    Set colListOfServices = objService.ExecQuery _ 
    ("Select * from Win32_Service Where StartMode = 'Auto' 
    AND Started = false")

    For Each objService in colListOfServices 
    WScript.Echo Date & " " & Time & objService.Caption

    Set xmlDoc = _
      CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM")  
    XMLDoc.async = False

    Set objRoot = _
      xmlDoc.createElement("ServerCheck")  
    xmlDoc.appendChild objRoot

    Set objRecord = _
      xmlDoc.createElement("Services") 
    objRoot.appendChild objRecord 

    For Each objName in colListOfServices 
    Set objName = _
      xmlDoc.createElement("Name")  
    objName.Text = objService.Caption
    objRecord.appendChild objName
    Next

    Set objDate = _
      xmlDoc.createElement("Date")  
    objDate.Text = Date & Time 
    objRecord.appendChild objDate  

    Set objIntro = _
      xmlDoc.createProcessingInstruction _
      ("xml","version='1.0'")  
    xmlDoc.insertBefore _
      objIntro,xmlDoc.childNodes(0)  

    xmlDoc.Save "C:\Users\111\Desktop\Audits.xml"
    Next
```

And my XML

```
Services><Name>Windows install</Name><Name>Windows install</Name>
<Name>Windows install</Name><Date>25.12.201215:51:19</Date>
```

WScript.Echo(to test) give me 3 different stopped serveces. But in my XML save only one service in 3 copys.
How can I save in XML all stopped services right?

Comment: I know vbs just a little. And didn't know PS. And can i do service from ps script?

Comment: You were supposed to add explaining text, not some meaningless blabla to make your post longer. And the error message appeared for a reason - I, for one, still have no idea what exactly you want to happen.

Comment: I want that my script write in XML all stopped services in Auto start mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want that my script write in XML all stopped services in Auto start mode.

Your problem is that you create and write a new XML file *within* the `For Each` loop. You keep overwriting the same file again and again, ending up with a file that contains the last stopped service only.

Create and save the XML outside of the loop.

```vb
Option Explicit

Dim objWmi, wql, objService, xmlDoc, objRoot, objRecord

Set objWmi = GetObject("winmgmts:\\.\Root\CIMV2")
wql = "SELECT * FROM Win32_Service WHERE StartMode = 'Auto' AND Started = false"

Set xmlDoc = CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument")
xmlDoc.async = False

Set objRoot = NewElement(xmlDoc, "ServerCheck", "")

For Each objService in objWmi.ExecQuery(wql)
    WScript.Echo Date & " " & Time & objService.Caption

    Set objRecord = NewElement(objRoot, "Services", "")

    NewElement objRecord, "Name", objService.Caption
    NewElement objRecord, "Date", Date & " " & Time
Next

xmlDoc.Save "C:\Users\111\Desktop\Audits.xml"

' --------------------------------------------------------------------
Function NewElement(parent, name, text)
    Set NewElement = parent.ownerDocument.createElement(name)
    If text <> "" Then NewElement.Text = text
    parent.appendChild NewElement
End Function
```

I've made a few other improvements, too.

Comment: Thanks for help. When i put For Each afte create document it's work. but in yours improvement not work this element Set NewElement = parent.ownerDocument.createElement(name). Error: Need object parent.ownerDocument